# Using Algolia to get timeline posts filtering by user permission

Tags: algorithm, search, social-networking, algolia

I am building a social network web site. In my social network user can set access permission for their own post. For example like facebook, they can set permission `only friends`, `only me`, `public`, `custom`. I am using the Algolia search engine to filter the posts for the user. When a user creates a post, I will save the post with the `permission` field which is `public` or `friends` and other. If it's `friends` I will add his/her friends `ids` in another filed named `accessList`.

```
Post {
  id: 'postId1334'
  text: 'This is a test'
  permission: 'Friends'
  accessList: ['userId1', 'userId123', 'userId2341', 'userId13455']
}
```

When a user opens the timeline I will `query` with the `filter= permission: Public OR accessList: currentUserId` which means find the posts which have ``public permission`or current user identifier includes the post`access list`.

Everything working well until we have changed in user `friend list`. If the user removes or adds a new user to his/her friend list they can see or not see some posts which saved with the permission of `Only Friends`. For this case, any change on user friend list I have to update all user posts accessList adapt with new friend list.

Is there another way to set permission for user access posts?

Or I need to use another kind of data structure?

Or maybe I need to change my query filter?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any need for change in the data structure.  Because Algolia is schemaless, the structure you describe is how you will replicate the "association" between Post and access list Users.

Comment: Thanks Ajay. Can you give me more details about your idea? any reference?

Comment: - You take care of updating Algolia index with new Post record `accessList` array of permitted `userId`s
- User opens their timeline to view posts

Comment: - Your application takes care of updating Algolia index with new Post `accessList` array of permitted `userId`s as needed using (updateObject)[https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/update-objects/]

- `userId1` opens their timeline to view Posts

- You query Posts index with (boolean operator)[https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/#boolean-operators] filter as you described: 

`filters: (permission=Public OR permission=Friends) AND (accessList: userId1)`

Comment: But this is what I am doing. My problem is when user1 add another user as a friend I need to look for all the post of user1 for example 1000 posts then update all adding new user id to the access list. I am looking for another way to save the cost of updating 1000 posts. For example if I could have access from one index to another index for query kind of join to check user friend list in another index instead of saving on post itself.

Comment: Keep in mind that Algolia is not a relational database, but indices of schemaless objects. The way to get the "join" relationships you want is exactly as you are already doing - an array attribute holding reference values. If you do figure out a method that you find useful, please feel free to post for the community!